# In Swift, how can I get an NSDate from a dispatch_time_t?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, grand-central-dispatch

"Walltime" is a little-known time format used by Grand Central Dispatch. Apple talks about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

There are some things it's really handy for, though, but it's a sticky wicket. It's hard to make it play nice with other time formats, which is what my question's about.

I can make a walltime by turning an `NSDate` into a `timespec`, and then using with `dispatch_walltime`:

```
 let now = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
 let nowWholeSecsFloor = floor(now)
 let nowNanosOnly = now - nowWholeSecsFloor
 let nowNanosFloor = floor(nowNanosOnly * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
 var thisStruct = timespec(tv_sec: Int(nowWholeSecsFloor),
 tv_nsec: Int(nowNanosFloor))
 let wallTime = dispatch_walltime(& thisStruct, 0)
```

But lord love a duck, I can't figure out how to get it back into an `NSDate`. Here's my try:

```
public func toNSDate(wallTime: dispatch_time_t)->NSDate {
    let wallTimeAsSeconds = Double(wallTime) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: wallTimeAsSeconds)
    return date
}
```

The resulting `NSDate` is not just off, but somewhat hilariously off, like five hundred years or something. As Martin R pointed out, the problem is that `dispatch_time_t` is an opaque value, with an undocumented representation of time.

Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: if the process of creating the walltime is confusing, this is basically what's going on:

`NSDate` defines time with a `Double`, and everything after the decimal point is the nanoseconds. `dispatch_time`, which can create a walltime, defines time with `UInt64`, so you have to convert between `Double` and `UInt64` to use it. To do that conversion you need to use a `timespec`, which takes seconds and nanoseconds as separate arguments, each of which must be `Int`.

A whole lotta convertin' going on!

Comment: First you need to define "wall time".  Most would interpret that to mean "10:04 AM" or some such.

Comment: Walltime isn't something I made up. Walltime is a format defined by Grand Central Dispatch, and apparently based on a standard used by Unix.

Comment: First time I ever heard it.  There is UNIX epoch time, which is milliseconds since the start of the UNIX epoch.  This is the most commonly used internet format.

Comment: If you command-click on `dispatch_time_t` then you'll find *"A somewhat abstract representation of time;"*. I have never seen a function to convert that back to UNIX seconds.

Comment: @MartinR timespec requires `Int` for creation.

Comment: @MartinR I don't know from Unix seconds, that's just what I've been told by other people on SO.

Comment: @rmaddy `NSDate` defines time with a `Double`, and everything after the decimal point is the nanoseconds. `dispatch_time`, which can create a walltime, defines time with `UInt64`, so you have to convert between `Double` and `UInt64` to use it. To do it you need to use a `timespec`, which takes seconds and nanoseconds as separate arguments, each of which must be `Int`. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: @rmaddy: OP computes the timespec from `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` (which is a Double), and *then* the dispatch_time_t from the timespec. There is no UInt64 involved in the first part. I have checked the `timespec` calculation and it is correct.

Comment: In any case: I think this is a valid question, and I can see no reason to close or downvote it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I removed my comments. (The down vote and closure are not mine).

Comment: @MartinR The reason given in the request for closure is that it's unclear what I'm asking. Can you recommend how I should clarify? It seems very clear to me.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced: *I* find it very clear now, but I have heard of dispatch_time_t before. The initial confusion might be caused by the fact that "wall time" is a very common term. You could add a link to the GCD docs (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/).

Comment: @LeMotJuiced: The *problem* is that dispatch_time_t is an opaque value, with an undocumented representation of time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The real answer is: **you can't**.

In the ["time.h"](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-442.1.4/dispatch/time.h) header file it is stated:

```
/*!
 * @typedef dispatch_time_t
 *
 * @abstract
 * A somewhat abstract representation of time; where zero means "now" and
 * DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER means "infinity" and every value in between is an
 * opaque encoding.
 */
typedef uint64_t dispatch_time_t;
```

So `dispatch_time_t` uses an undocumented "abstract" representation of time, which
may even change between releases.

**That being said**, let's have some fun and try to figure out what
a `dispatch_time_t` really is. So we have a look at ["time.c"](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-442.1.4/src/time.c), which contains the implementation of
`dispatch_walltime()`:

```
dispatch_time_t
dispatch_walltime(const struct timespec *inval, int64_t delta)
{
    int64_t nsec;
    if (inval) {
        nsec = inval->tv_sec * 1000000000ll + inval->tv_nsec;
    } else {
        nsec = (int64_t)_dispatch_get_nanoseconds();
    }
    nsec += delta;
    if (nsec <= 1) {
        // -1 is special == DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER == forever
        return delta >= 0 ? DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER : (dispatch_time_t)-2ll;
    }
    return (dispatch_time_t)-nsec;
}
```

The interesting part is the last line: it takes the *negative* value of the
nanoseconds, and this value is cast back to an (unsigned) `dispatch_time_t`. There are also some special cases.

Therefore, to reverse the conversion, we have to *negate* the
`dispatch_time_t` and take that as nanoseconds:

```
public func toNSDate(wallTime: dispatch_time_t)->NSDate {

    // Tricky part HERE:
    let nanoSeconds = -Int64(bitPattern: wallTime)

    // Remaining part as in your question:
    let wallTimeAsSeconds = Double(nanoSeconds) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: wallTimeAsSeconds)
    return date
}
```

And indeed, this converts the walltime correctly back to the original
`NSDate`, at least when I test it in an OS X application.

But again: **don't do it!** You would rely on an undocumented representation which could change between OS releases. There may also
be special cases that are not considered in the above code.
Also the representation in the iOS runtime could be different, I did
not try that.
*You have been warned!*

Comment: Great answer, thanks! This is one of the best, least dismissive answers I've recieved here. And thanks for gainsaying the closure vote, too. It means something.

Comment: In this example context, is `wallTime: dipatch_time_t` the same value as exposed by DispatchTime's `let rawValue: dispatch_time_t`?  When I created an extension: `var seconds: TimeInterval { Double(-Int64(bitPattern: rawValue)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) }` and use it to create a date with your 1970 option, I am seeing an incorrect result.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisConover: I don't know. But `DispatchWallTime.now().rawValue` gives a dispatch_time_t value that converts  correctly to the current date with the above code.

Comment: Great answer indeed. As  dispatch_time_t is created usually with a timespec (+ delta nsec) maybe there's some "less abstract" converter to the mid-way timespec? Here of course I also assume timespec is safely convertible to NSDate/NSTimeInterval...